# Not reading / opening of root file from uproot

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, uproot

I am trying to read a file.root using ** uproot** but it's throwing back this error :-

File "/Users/siddharthkeshar/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uproot/source/chunk.py", line 370, in wait
raise OSError(
OSError: expected Chunk of length 395,
received 0 bytes from MemmapSource
for file path /Users/siddharthkeshar/Harnod/data/file/file.root

How can i resolve this error ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.